# Having problems with the DS3231.h library

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Dear Stack Exchange community.

I'm a beginner Arduino user and am attempting to replicate a 24-hour alarm clock demonstrated in a tutorial found at: https://diyhacking.com/arduino-alarm-clock-using-real-time-clock-lcd-screen/.

I downloaded and installed all the most updated libraries associated with the DS3231 Real Time Clock module.

When I attempt to run the following program (I am not the author of this code, as it is directly taken from the page I linked above), I am met with an error that seems to be a result of missing a key library.

Can anyone tell me which libraries I need to install to eliminate the error?

```
#include <DS3231.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);
Time  t;
#define buz 11

int Hor;
int Min;
int Sec;
void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  rtc.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buz, OUTPUT);
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("DIYHacking.com");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Arduino Alarm ");
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  t = rtc.getTime();
  Hor = t.hour;
  Min = t.min;
  Sec = t.sec;
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Time: ");
  lcd.print(rtc.getTimeStr());
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Date: ");
  lcd.print(rtc.getDateStr());
  if( Hor == 11 &&  (Min == 32 || Min == 33)) {
    //Comparing the current time with the Alarm time
    Buzzer();
    Buzzer();
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Alarm ON");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Alarming");
    Buzzer();
    Buzzer();
  }
  delay(1000);
}

void Buzzer() {
  digitalWrite(buz,HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(buz, LOW);
  delay(500);
}
```

The error returned when I compile and run this program is as follows:

```
sketch_oct29c:17: error: no matching function for call to 
'DS3231::DS3231(const uint8_t&, const uint8_t&)'

 DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);

                 ^
```

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

The following libraries are those that I installed:

- DS3231,
- MD_DS3231,
- Rtc_by_Makuna,
- RTClib,
- RTCtime

Cheers!

Comment: Downloading a library is one thing and installing it is another thing. Did you install the library in `libraries` folder?

Comment: Yes, all libraries installed

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ds3231-precision-rtc-breakout/overview

Comment: It depends on which library you installed, which we can't see. You should read the docs for the one you installed, and/or make sure you're using the one you think you are.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question with the libraries I installed.

Comment: If it just complains that the constructor should take a uint8_t reference, you might be able to do: `static const uint8_t pinsda = SDA; static const uint8_t pinscl = SCL; DS3231 rtc(pinsda, pinscl);`.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same error and had to google for a number of days to get it sorted out. Seems the issue is being caused by the library.

You need to download the Rinky Dink DS 3231 library. You can download it from [here](http://rinkydinkelectronics.com/library.php?id=73)

Once downloaded, extract the DS3231 folder and place it into the libraries folder of your Arduino. Once you've done that, run the program and it would work. Hopefully.